# NodeJs EJS render and include not getting parameters passed in

Tags: node.js, ejs

NodeJS newbie.

I have a login page that valid the input against a database table.

I want to then save a few details in a session variable/object, and then references that session object in any/all pages that get rendered or included.

My login handles the return from query as below:

```
              if (results.length > 0) {
                 request.session.loggedin = true;
                 request.session.uaccEmail = uaccEmail;
                 request.session.uaccID = fields[0].uacc_id;
                 request.session.uaccName = fields[0].uacc_name;
                 request.session.uaccOrgID = fields[0].uacc_org_id;
                 response.redirect('/home');
                 return( true );
              } else {
                 response.send('Incorrect Username and/or Password!', fields);
                 return( false );
              }
```

Note the response.redirect('/home'), which is handled here:

```
app.get('/home', function(request, response) {
   console.log ( '/home' );
   if (request.session.loggedin) {
      //response.send('Welcome back, ' + request.session.uaccEmail + '!');
      response.render('pages/index', { request: request, response: response });
   } else {
      response.send('Please login to view this page!');
   }
   //response.end();
});
```

pages/index.ejs has the following at the  top:

And header.ejs has at the top:

```
  <div class='toplink'> <%= request.session.uaccName %> @ <%= request.session.uaccOrgID %>  </div>
```

When I run this I get an error:

```
/home
(node:143518) UnhandledPromiseRejectionWarning: ReferenceError: /u01/WorkSpace/node/views/pages/index.ejs:10
    8| 
    9| <header>
 >> 10|   <%- include('../partials/header', { request: request, response: response }); %>
    11| </header>
    12| 
    13| <div class='centerBox'>

request is not defined
```

The `request` and `response` objects are not getting passed along.

What am I doing wrong?